# Github Actions workflow will not trigger

Tags: github-actions, workflow

I am trying to trigger a workflow every time a commit is pushed to the repo. This little workflow adds a label to a jira ticket every time a commit is pushed. Whenever i would commit this workflow file and add a commit message, it would trigger the workflow but when i try it with other files in the repo it does absolutely nothing and I don't have a clue why. When i would also make changes to other workflow files it would also trigger this specific workflow.

I'm new to github actions so any help would be appreciated. Below is my full workflow. I have also tried with just "on: push:".

```
name: Update Jira with branch name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  update_jira:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Get branch name
      run: echo "Branch name:${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"

    - name: Login
      uses: atlassian/gajira-login@master
      env:
        JIRA_BASE_URL: x
        JIRA_USER_EMAIL: y
        JIRA_API_TOKEN: z
        
    - name: Find in commit messages
      uses: atlassian/gajira-find-issue-key@v3
      with:
        from: commits

    - name: Update Jira with branch name
      run: |
        JIRA_URL=x
        JIRA_USERNAME=y
        JIRA_TOKEN=z
        curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "$JIRA_USERNAME:$JIRA_TOKEN" | base64)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"fields\":{\"labels\":[\"${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}\"]}}" "$JIRA_URL/rest/api/latest/issue/$(cat /home/runner/jira/config.yml | grep "issue:" | awk '{print $2}')"
        
        # Get the response code
        response_code=$(curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "$JIRA_USERNAME:$JIRA_TOKEN" | base64)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"fields\":{\"labels\":[\"${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}\"]}}" "$JIRA_URL/rest/api/latest/issue/$(cat /home/runner/jira/config.yml | grep "issue:" | awk '{print $2}')" -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}")
        # Print the response code
        echo "Response code: $response_code"
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please elaborate "**when i try it with other files in the repo it does absolutely nothing**" a bit? Are all your workflow on the same branch? The one above in the question is on the default branch?

Comment: Yes, all workflows are located in the same branch (default branch). What I really want is for it to label Jira tickets with the name of the branch so that I can see which tickets are in which branches. So I created this workflow to accomplish that. I currently have about 13 branches. This workflow does not trigger whenever I commit something from those branches, but I expected it to because I specified at the start that it should trigger whenever a commit is pushed no matter the branch.

Comment: Right. Try `on: push` without `branches` or `branches: ['**']`. Relevant: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-events-to-trigger-workflows and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet

Comment: i have actually already tried that and it will still not trigger the workflow... Now i actually noticed it only triggers for changes in the master branch. The workflow is of course in the master branch but it should still trigger for all branches right?

Comment: Yes, unless there are other conflicting configurations preventing it. Please edit your question and add a minimal, reproducible example with multiple branches. I'll try to test your complete scenario on my side. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with conflicting configurations? As in that some branches are protected? I have checked all settings and everything seemed alright

Comment: i just checked all other branches and those don't have the workflows folder. do i need to add those to every branch i want this workflow to work on

Comment: Are your branches not created from your default branch?

Comment: Yes they are but should that mean that they automatically also have the workflows folder? Wouldn't i first have to merge those branches to get that result? Or create a new branch?

Comment: I think it's better if you could update your question with your complete use case. With a small example that covers your requirements, it would be much easier to test, iterate, and fix it.

Comment: I just tried creating a new branch from the master branch and i pushed something in that new branch and it triggered the workflow so now i just need to add this to all existing branches. Thank you for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, right. So, the other branches didn't have the workflow, to begin with. That makes sense. I believe you can figure out the rest easily. Good luck and welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

The workflow only runs with this 'on: push' setup if the workflow is stored on that branch. Check if the workflow exists on those other branches as well, and add it if missing.